# Why this two code snippet for using Move semantic but the next doesn't?

Tags: c++11, move

Base on this artical, http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/when-is-it-safe-to-move-an-object-instea/240156579#disqus_thread

Following code will NOT call the move constructor:

```
void func()
{
    Thing t;
    work_on(t);
    // never using t variable again ...
}
```

Following code will call the move constructor:

```
work_on(Thing());
```

The reason is for the first code snippet, the constructor may save the constructing object address, and use it later.

My question is:
But for the second code snippet, the temp object still are alive before work_on finished base on the C++ standard, so the author can also save the address of the constructing object, and use it inside work_on function.
So base on the same reason, it also shouldn't call move constructor, doesn't this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got all your reasons wrong. There's nothing about "saving addresses". (Anyone can write any manner of horribly broken code by randomly storing addresses. That's not an argument.)

The simple reason is that in the first snippet, `t` continues living and can be used, so you can't move from it:

```
Thing t;

work_on(t);

t.x = 12;
foo(t);
```

In the second snippet, though, the temporary value `Thing()` only lives on that one line, till the end of the full-expression, so nobody can *possibly* refer to that value after the end of the statement. Thus it's perfectly safe to move from (i.e. mutate) the object.

Comment: But how about our function just have two line of code, and didn't using the t variable after the function work_on called. Isn't it legal to call the move constructor?

Comment: That's actually an interesting question.  If the compiler can see during static analysis that an automatic storage duration variable isn't used after the call of `work_on(t)`, why doesn't it automatically mark it as an xvalue instead of an lvalue.  I guess that although it might not be used, it or one of its subobjects may be indirectly referenced and used, which is not as easy to detect.  The programmer must explicitly mark it as an xvalue with `move(t)`

Comment: @ZijingWu: If you're not going to use `t` again, say `work_on(std::move(t));`.

Comment: Agree that: "Anyone can write any manner of horribly broken code by randomly storing addresses. That's not an argument."

Answer (score 1):

```
void func()
{
    Thing t;

    work_on(t);       // <--- POINT 1

    work_on(move(t)); // <--- POINT 2

    work_on(Thing()); // <--- POINT 3
}
```

The expression `t` at POINT 1 is an `lvalue`.

The expression `move(t)` at POINT 2 is an `xvalue`.

The expression `Thing()` at POINT 3 is a `prvalue`.

Based on this *value category* of an expression, a best viable function is chosen from the overloaded set.

Suppose the two available functions were:

```
work_on(const Thing&); // lvalue reference version
work_on(Thing&&);      // rvalue reference version
```

An `lvalue` will select the lvalue reference version, and will never bind to the rvalue reference version.

An `xvalue` or `prvalue` (collectively called `rvalues`) will viably bind to either, but will select the rvalue reference version as the better match if available.

Inside the implementation of the two versions of `work_on`, the parameters are largely the same.  The purpose of this is that the rvalue reference version can assume that the argument is theirs to modify or move.  So it may call the move constructor on its argument - whereas the lvalue reference version should not.

So suppose we had some `vector<Thing> V` that `work_on` should add their parameter to:

```
void work_on(Thing&& t)
{
    V.push_back(move(t));
}

void work_on(const Thing& t)
{
    V.push_back(t);
}
```

`std::vector::push_back` is overloaded in a similar fashion to `work_on`, and a similar overload resolution takes place.  Inside the two different implementations of `push_back`, the rvalue reference version will call the move constructor to push the value onto its array, possibly destroying `t`.  The lvalue reference version will call the copy constructor, leaving `t` intact.

The main purpose of this language mechanic is simply to keep track of variables (lvalues), intentionally marked expiring values (xvalues) and temporaries (prvalues) - so we know when we can safely reuse their resources (move them) and when we can copy them.